# How to store secrets for a Python Flask App on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple Flask App that uses Stripe running on an EC2 instance.

I followed this guide to get it running: https://medium.com/techfront/step-by-step-visual-guide-on-deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-ec2-8e3e8b82c4f7

I export the keys as environment variables and then in the code read them.

```
stripe_keys = {
    "secret_key": os.environ["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"],
    "publishable_key": os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"],
    "webhook_secret": os.environ["STRIPE_WEBHOOK_KEY"],
}
```

However, this requires me to SSH into the EC2 machines to set the variables. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend AWS System Manager - Parameter Store

1. maintain your keys in SSM Parameter Store, choose SecureString type so your keys are encrypted at rest
2. give your EC2 instance IAM role enough permissions to fetch and decrypt your SecureString stored in SSM Parameter Store
3. make sure your EC2 instance can reach the Internet, as SSM Parameter Store is an Internet-facing service
4. in your code, use AWS SDK to fetch and decrypt your SecureString stored in SSM Parameter Store

I reckon you're writing in Python, so https://nqbao.medium.com/how-to-use-aws-ssm-parameter-store-easily-in-python-94fda04fea84

PS: if you use CloudFormation or other Infra-as-Code tools to provision your EC2 instances, most IaC tools support injecting SSM Parameter Store as env vars during deployment. With this approach, your code can stay as is, your EC2 instance doesn't need extra permission.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Chen pointed out, you can use AWS Parameter Store and on top of it: [AWStanding](https://github.com/jiss2891/awstanding)

Suppose you stored your variables like this in Parameter store:

```py
    "/stripe/secret_key"
    "/stripe/publishable_key"
    "/stripe/webhook_secret"
```

Then you can write code like this:

```py
from awstanding.parameter_store import load_path

load_path('/stripe')

# Now you can access you variables exactly like this:
os.environ["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"]
os.environ["STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET"]

# or store them in settings variables:
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
```

Also, it handles automatically any encrypted key.